xslt3.0 - accumulator is not getting updated with blank value
Input XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Entry>
        <Tag1>A1</Tag1>
        <Tag2>B1</Tag2>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Tag1>A2</Tag1>
        <Tag2/>
    </Entry>
</Root>

XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="Tag2" as="xs:string"
        initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Tag2/text()" 
            select="." />
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*" expand-text="yes">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        Tag2 {accumulator-after('Tag2')}
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output:
    Tag2 B1

I am expecting the output as Tag2 <<empty>> as the 2nd element does not have value defined against Tag2.
Is there anyway we can check and make sure accumulator considers the cases when there is no value against the node?

FYI - I have prepared above snippet by referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983320/conditional-streaming-accumulator-in-xslt-3

You match on text() nodes, there is no text node in an empty element

Add a rule matching the element that sets the value to the empty string

You match on text() nodes, there is no text node in an empty element.
Add a rule matching the element that sets the value to the empty string:
<xsl:accumulator name="Tag2" as="xs:string"
    initial-value="''" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Tag2" select="''"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Tag2/text()" 
        select="." />
</xsl:accumulator>


I think probably match="Entry" was intended rather than match="Tag". Or perhaps match="Tag2", depending on exactly what effect you want.

@MichaelKay, thanks, I had wanted to type Tag2, now corrected.

@aj2288, good to hear. Consider to accept the answer so that your question is marked as resolved.
